# How to assign users in groups from Django views?

Tags: django, python-3.8, django-2.2

I have CRUD operations for users, which can be done only from the admin role. I have 6 different roles, that I made by creating groups and assign users to specific group from the admin panel.

My question is is there some way to include these group fields with drop down menu when admin create new user, so he can choose what group to assign the new user but not from the admin panel?

any help would be appreciated :)

**model.py**

```
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):

        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_('The Email must be set'))
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):

        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_staff=True.'))
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.'))
        return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):

    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    username                        = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, default='')
    is_superuser                    = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin                        = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_employee                     = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_headofdepartment             = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_reception                    = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_patient                      = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_active                       = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff                        = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
class UserForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['email', 'password',]
```

**useradd.html**

```
<h1 class="display-4">Add new user</h1>
            <form action="" method="post" autocomplete="off">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.as_p }}
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save </button>
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
@admin_only
def users(request):
    context = {'users': CustomUser.objects.all()}
    return render(request, 'users.html', context)

@login_required
def users_add(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            users = CustomUser.objects.create_user(**form.cleaned_data)
            #login(request, users)
            # redirect, or however you want to get to the main view
            return redirect('feedback:users')
    else:
        form = UserForm() 

    return render(request, 'useradd.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Do you want it in admin part of your site (django admin)?

Comment: @DmitryBelaventsev I created the groups from the django admin panel, but I want to assign users from the views, not from the django admin panel. Like with drop down menu from the add users form

Comment: Do you want to include all the groups you have or just some subset of them?

Comment: @DmitryBelaventsev I'm trying to include all the groups I have. For me there are 6 different roles

Comment: Could you show your view where do you use UserForm?

Comment: In general you should build `<select><option ...></option>...</select>` element in template. Data used in `<option>` elements - is what you get from `Group.objects.all()` queryset.

Comment: I edit my question with some of the views for users. Could you please take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) to include `select` widget in your form. So please try this code:

**forms.py**

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.forms import ModelForm, ModelChoiceField

from app.model import CustomUser


class UserForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = [
            'email',
            'password',
        ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['group'] = ModelChoiceField(
            queryset=Group.objects.all(),
            empty_label='No group'
        )
```

Change `CustomUserManager.create_user` method in **model.py**

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group


class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, email: str, password: str, group: Group, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_('The Email must be set'))

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()

        if group is not None:
            group.user_set.add(user)

        return user
```

Comment: Awesome my groups are now printed in the view! But I can't assign them to a user. I didn't get the ModelChoiceField, I tried to add it in forms.py with group = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Group.objects.all()) but it looks like it doesn't save anything from my choice field.

Comment: Can you debug and check what value is passed to user creation function?

Comment: I'm not sure how to debug django in VScode:( I'm trying to pass print(form.cleaned_data['group']) but all I get is an error

Comment: I checked it saved in database, that means I assign them to user, only I can't find how to display them

Comment: So your users are getting connected with groups, right? If so, then what's the last issue you want to resolve?

Comment: I think I'm missing something, because they didn't show in my views when I assign them to exact user, that's why I checked the database but I can't figure it out why the groups aren't show in the views too.

Comment: Do you mean in `users` view? If so, then the answer is simple - you don't have groups information in the context passed to template. If you want to display something in a template, you should pass it to a context